# How can I detect which programs installed malware?

Tags: malware, file-search

Currently I am attacked by malware.

I try to use Kaspersky Internet Security + manually delete suspicious folders.

However, Whenever I restart my computer, some suspicious folders reappear and my google chrome and firefox are attacked.

That's, I believe there are some files that Kaspersky Internet Security and my bare eyes cannot detected, which continuously install malware into my computer.

Now, I want to trace back which files installed the suspicious folders.

Please help me to do that. Thank you!

Comment: By the time the folders are created it's too late.

Comment: Nothing is installing malware at this point, you're simply removing infection symptoms instead of actual malware.

Comment: "Now, I want to trace back which files installed the suspicious folders." - Unless you enabled the right logs, its very unlikely, you will be able to determine this from the information you have left.

Answer (score -1):

You can boot into safe mode and then one by one narrow down the additional startup tasks or processes you have running that are causing the behavior.